# Alternative of blur effect on DrawingVisual

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, drawing

I want to give a blur effect to my `DrawingVisual`. I can do this using `BitmapEffect` properties like:

```
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
var effect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurBitmapEffect();
effect.Radius = 10;
drawingVisual.BitmapEffect = effect;
```

But the compiler give me a warning that Bitmap effect properties is obsolete.

What other alternative I can use to achive the effect on `DrawingVisual`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effect property of DrawingVisual in not support in 3.5SP1 but there is another way to achieve this to apply shader effect to visual. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/12fbdc6d-0850-4379-b357-bc8a0abc03f3) is the example how we can apply shader effect to DrawingVisual

Answer (score 1):

`DrawingVisual`s do not yet support the new [`Effect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect.aspx) methodology that uses pixel shaders (the built-in `BlurEffect` is what you should be using). You can either wait until they do, or you can workaround it by rendering your visuals into an `Image` of some sort and using the `Image.Effect` property.