# C# - How can I add background blur to an element in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add an acrylic/aero glass blur on anything that's under an object in WPF? All the results that I've found talk about how to blur the actual window, but not the elements under an object.

In CSS, this can be achieved using the [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#result) property, but I need an equivalent in C#.

This is what I am trying to achieve (Figma Mockup):

[image: Example]

And here is another example:

[image: Other Example]

Comment: Maybe this might help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815278/blur-the-background-of-the-wpf-container

Comment: I believe wpf does not support this acrylic out of the box. Easiest way would be just to get styles for it, for example you can look into this project https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF